# Reproducing WSO2 IoT demo

Tags: iot, wso2, wso2-iot

I am new to WSO2 and like to evaluate the product for a specific IoT use case involving Raspberry Pi.

I found this nice article with the IoT demo, but could need some help reproducing it:

http://wso2.com/library/articles/2014/09/demonstration-on-architecture-of-internet-of-things-an-analysis/

Github repository is here:
https://github.com/dulichan/iot-ref-arch/releases/tag/0.0.1

There are three components involved:

1. Message Broker
2. Complex Event Processor
3. Enterprise Mobility Manager (EMM)

Is there a more detailed description about how to setup the components?

I managed to run the rpi agent on raspberry and to run EMM on my server machine, but where to put the files in the folders "cep-resources" ?

Also I foud few information on how to enroll the raspberry in EMM, is this possible by default with the user token in EMM or do I have to make any adjustments?

Comment: cep-resources contains the deployment artifacts for the Complex Event Processor 3.1.0. the stream-definitions.xml file should go to <CEP>/repository/conf/data-bridge directory. Other directories should go to <CEP>/repository/deployment/server (replace)

Comment: On a related note, I wanted to understand how to enroll using the python-agent. I did manage to build the rpi-agent (Java) alongwith the maven install on rpi, but I think the python-agent will be more lightweight for an rpi hardware constrained environment. The error is regarding the enrollment url which kicks in once self enrollment is attempted at url -> `https://localhost:9453/temp-controller-agentr/enrollment/enroll`. This obviously fails with I am not sure what WSO2 server this should point out to on my laptop, but I am assuming it has to be the WSO2 EMM server.

Comment: I tried changing the dmURL to https://my.localnetwork.ip.address:9443/emm/api/devices/register/1.0.0/ and I got this response `<ams:fault xmlns:ams="http://wso2.org/apimanager/security"><ams:code>900901</ams:code><ams:message>Invalid Credentials</ams:message><ams:description>Access failure for API: /emm/api/devices/register, version: 1.0.0 with key: null</ams:description></ams:fault>`

Comment: I am able to get past this, but I have a different stack trace on the WSO2 EMM server log -> `ERROR {org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager} -  org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot read property "id" from undefined (/emm/modules/device.js#1163) {org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager}
org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot read property "id" from undefined (/emm/modules/device.js#1163) at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:571)`. This is a RaspberryPI.

Comment: that file is located in <EMM>/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/emm/modules/device.js

Comment: in the past i once found an issue in device.js where a nested for loop used the same variable 'i' as in outer loop. i guess this can be somewhat similar issue (similar error msg). so look above that line #1163 for such occurrences. you can simply edit and save that file to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use WSO2 IoT Server 1.0.0 Alpha which was released recently which has the necessary components packed OOB. You can download the pack from [1]. This release has a Raspberry pi sample [2] which uses DHT11 temperature sensor and a LED bulb which you can tryout. Also you can write your own device plugin by referring [3].

[1] https://github.com/wso2/product-iots/releases/tag/v1.0.0-alpha

[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IoTS100/Raspberry+Pi

[3] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IoTS100/Creating+a+New+Device+Type